# Как научиться грамотно писать?1

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы

Вот скажите, у меня все эти правила не укладываются в голове, хоть убейте.. есть ли другие способы грамотно писать? А то не хочется быть безграмотным...

Answer (score 5):

Всё зависит от того, насколько грамотным Вы хотите стать.
На первом месте, конечно, чтение русской классики.
На втором - ОТЛИЧНОЕ знание всех частей речи. Только в этом случае "заработают" правила, применимые к конкретной части речи.
На третьем - умение видеть структуру слова, мгновенно, в случае затруднения, разобрать его мысленно на морфемы и применить правило касательно данной морфемы. 
На четвёртом - очень хорошее знание основных правил орфографии и пунктуации. 
Если Вы всё это усвоили, Вам остаётся научиться применять правила на практике. А это и есть главное умение. Всё в русской орфографии базируется на знании частей речи, состава слова  и, конечно, правил.
Вы сейчас смеётесь, но, опираясь только на чтение, вы добьётесь лишь относительно хороших результатов. Ошибок не избежать. Ведь, чтобы написать правильно "выкач..нная бочка" и "выкач..нная вода" или "подр..внять грядки" и "подр..внять волосы", Вам придётся всё-таки применить какие-то знания. 
 О пунктуации и говорить нечего. Не зная правил, вы будете бесконечно ставить лишние знаки, или не будете ставить нужные, или замените нужные на ненужные.

Comment: Поэтому и чтение, и списывание, и правила! В таком порядке. На мой взгляд...

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы научиться чему-то, нужно **осознанное отношение** к учёбе. Не "учить правила", а постараться понять **смысл правил**, глубинную природу того или иного написания.
2. Не обязательно глубоко изучать ВСЕ правила, но лучше "правильно", с полным пониманием изучить одно, чем вызубрить 5 (важен сам принцип).
3. ВСЕ правила изучить вообще нельзя. Специалист в вопросах правописания отличается от дилетанта именно тем, что *знает границы своей компетентности* и вовремя обращается к словарям и справочникам.

Чтение книг не делает человека грамотным *автоматически* (вообще очень мало здесь помогает, я бы оценил эту помощь примерно в 1/10 от работы с правилами - и то при обязательном наличии такой работы).

*Переписывание* я бы отнёс к альтернативному варианту повышения грамотности (вместо изучения правил), но переписывание не чего попало (уж никак не "Войны и мира"), а строго тех текстов, которые относятся к вашей текущей деятельности. В каждой деятельности есть свой набор характерных слов, выражений, оборотов, штампов, - их можно и нужно заучивать. Но опять же нельзя заучить ВСЁ (лексикон математика очень сильно отличается от лексикона историка или какого-нибудь "офис-менеджера").

Comment: Лично я пишу, надеюсь, довольно грамотно - за счёт чтения книг. Не на 1/10, а на все 70-80%. Советы Ваши считаю правильными, но у каждого свой путь к грамоте (и вообще - к знаниям). Злоупотребляю применением "тире", потому что по смыслу хочу что-то подчеркнуть противу всех правил. Не знаю, насколько это неграмотно выглядит, но вот - хочется! Это моё авторское право!

Comment: @post, мне знаком другой тип людей: непрерывно читает книги одну за другой (всё подряд: классику, детективы...), но пишет безграмотно. 

Отсюда я делаю вывод о том, что ваша грамотность возникла не только от чтения книг.

Comment: Разумеется, грамотность письма есть следствие нескольких факторов. Если человек читает много, но пишет неграмотно (или, тем более, безграмотно), то у него некоторые кнопочки в мозгу не работают; в частности, не включена кнопка зрительной памяти вкупе с механизмом анализа собственного письма - это скорее всего. Человек не считает грамотность письма важным качеством личности. Так грязнуля может ходить в не чищенных ботинках, но в остальном быть довольно чистоплотным.Это логически необъяснимая странность, но такое реально вполне возможно (собственный пример). В жизни возможно всё!

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о буквенной орфографии, то пишите не слова, а морфемы в следующей очередности: приставка, корень, суффикс, окончание. Приставок в русском языке мало (около 40), проблемных суффиксов тоже немного (списочек себе составьте). Окончания - это грамматика, у нас всего-то три склонения существительных и два спряжения глаголов. Что делать с корнями? Многие корни проверяются, но для этого надо понимать их значение. Чередующихся корне немного - им придется уделить особое внимание. Непроверяемые гласные и согласные - это словарь (орфографический и этимологический). Поэтому с лексикой языка надо работать постоянно - прислушиваться к словам.

И еще очень важно знание фонетики - прямо с нее и начинайте. Только нужен не формальный разбор для ЕГЭ, а понимание фонетических процессов (особенность каждого звука и его поведение в реальной речи).

Как видите, я ни разу не сказала слово "правило". В орфографии очень немного орфографии, все остальное - это фонетика, грамматика, лексика, словообразование. Кстати, грамотная письменная речь формируется на основе правильной устной речи (орфография - это правильная запись звукового текста).